# Vue 3 defineProps() Error: [plugin:vite:vue] Transform failed

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am using Vue version 3.2 and TypeScript.
When I want to define my props like this:

```
<!-- AppButton.vue -->

<script lang="ts">
  interface Iprops {
    buttonType?: string;
    size?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    loading?: boolean;
  }
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  const props = defineProps<Iprops>();
</script>
```

When running the code, I get this error:
[image]

I searched a lot but did not find any results

Answer (score 2):

The `interface` should be declared inside the `script setup`, since the other script is usually used to declare `inheritAttrs` or `name` :

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>

    interface Iprops {
    buttonType?: string;
    size?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    loading?: boolean;
  }
  const props = defineProps<Iprops>();
</script>
```

Also imported types and complex ones are not supported for argument declaration type.

> As of now, the type declaration argument must be one of the following to ensure correct static analysis:

- A type literal
- A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

Comment: Thank you. Only I wrote my code like this in the setup to avoid getting an error: `export interface Iprops {`

Comment: You're welcome, I recommend to define prop types like `const titleProps = {
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    description: 'Title of the component',
  },
}

export default titleProps
` to get type checking in runtime